# Knockout viewModel Property

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel, computed-observable

I just can't get this to work after trying hours' worth of ideas.

Simple need: I have a textbox (INPUT type TEXT) and a Div tag:

```
<body>
    <input id="tb" type="text"/>
    <div id="Words" data-bind="text: WordCount"></div>
</body>
```

Ideally, all I want to do is update the WordCount each time the user types a new character into the tb text box.

In an effort to do that, I created a ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.recalcFlag = ko.observable();

    self.WordCount = ko.computed(function () {
        self.recalcFlag();
        return CountWords($("#tb").wijinputtext("option", "text"))
    }, this);

    self.recalcWordCount = function () {
        self.recalcFlag.notifySubscribers();
    }
}
```

The CountWords function I'm using looks like this:

```
function CountWords(inputString) {

    var splitArray = inputString.split(" "), obj = {};

    for (var x = 0; x < splitArray.length; x++) {
        if (obj[splitArray[x]] === undefined) {
            obj[splitArray[x]] = 1;
        } else {
            obj[splitArray[x]]++;
        }
    }

    return splitArray.length;
}
```

The technique above is one I saw as a solution in another SO post--a way to get a computed ko value to refresh/update on-demand. The idea is to call recalcWordCount from a keypress function. But the problem is that my recalcWordCount function is inside my ViewModel object--and Knockout has already created an instance of that. I don't know how to get to ko's instance of the ViewModel in order to call the function. For example, this doesn't work:

```
<input id="tb" type="text" onkeypress="recalcWordCount();" />
```

Also, this doesn't work:

```
<input id="tb" type="text" onkeypress="ViewModel.recalcWordCount();" />
```

Also, this doesn't work:

```
<input id="tb" type="text" onkeypress="ko.viewModel.recalcWordCount();" />
```

I would appreciate any suggestion on how can I get this to work.

Comment: If you create a fiddle I bet someone can help you figure out your problem within minutes

Comment: Will use fiddle in the future--I just learned about fiddle so I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an observable 'filter' and bind it with the input like this:

```
  <input data-bind="value: filter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

and then use the observable in the computed 'WordCount'

```
self.WordCount = ko.computed(function () {
        var filter = this.filter();
        return CountWords(filter)
    }, this);
```

Comment: Wow, you added many hours back to my life. Thank you.
For those who want to implement the above, be sure to add a filter variable to the view model:

filter = ko.observable("");

If you don't you will get a JS error that filter() is not defined.